# Find data from multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have following tables with columns.

```
 Manager(tabel) 
 | manager_id | manager_type |
   1             X
   2             Y
   3             Z

 Employee(table) 
 | emp_id | emp_name |
   1         A 
   2         B
   3         C

 ManagerEmployee(table)
 | id | manager_id | emp_id |
   1      1           1
   2      1           2
   3      2           3
   4      2           1
   5      2           2

 Workspace(table)
 | id | manager_id | description | Revenue|
   1       1           ......       20 
   2       2           ......       10
   3       1           ......       20
   4       1           ......       10
   5       2           ......       10
```

I want to calculate total revenue from **Workspace** table of all the managers. where the manager has manager_type = 'X' (Manager table). And the employees of that manager have worked with other Managers (relation mentioned in ManagerEmployee table).

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: @ParagTyagi Thanks for you reply. Actually, first i need to get employees (emp_id = 1) that have worked with manager "x"(manager_id = 1) and those employees have also worked with other managers(manager_id = 2). and once all managers are identified (manager_id = (1,2))than calculate the total revenue for those managers. In an single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the revenue sum from workspace you can use join with manager table this can be achieved by

```
select 
m.manager_id,
sum(w.Revenue) 
from Workspace w
join Manager m on(m.manager_id = w.manager_id)
where m.manager_type ='X'
group by m.manager_id;
```

And to know the employees that worked for more than one manager you can calculate and compare the count must b greater than 1

```
select distinct m.* 
from  Manager m
join ManagerEmployee me on(m.manager_id = me.manager_id)
group by me.emp_id
having count(distinct  me.manager_id) > 1
```

Now for your final task that  only sum where manager type is X and their employees have worked for other managers too you can combine both queries to produce your desired results

```
select 
m.manager_id,
sum(w.Revenue) 
from Workspace w
join Manager m on(m.manager_id = w.manager_id)
join (
select distinct m.* 
from  Manager m
join ManagerEmployee me on(m.manager_id = me.manager_id)
group by me.emp_id
having count(distinct  me.manager_id) > 1
) mm 
on (m.manager_id = mm.manager_id)
where m.manager_type ='X'
group by m.manager_id;
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60361/6)

Comment: Thank you for your support. Your solution is calculating sum of revenue for only manager with type"X". My point is, total revenue should also  include the revenue of those managers with common employees as that of manager "X".(If one employee exist we will choose that manager and will show the sum of all against manager "X")

Comment: @AhsanMohyuddin can you ask another question regarding your above point  and also provide me the link of your new question i will try to answer it as well